# Understanding effects of Domino command to restart HTTP server

Tags: cluster-computing, lotus-domino

We have a Domino cluster which consists of two servers. Recently we see that one of the server has memory problems, and the HTTP service goes down after 2 hours. So we plan to implement a scheduled server task which runs the command nserver -c "restart task http" till we find the memory leak solution. The HTTP service restarts in say 15 seconds. But what would happen if a user submits data during this small period. Will the cluster manager automatically manage the user session using the other server, and hence load balance the submit task?. Not sure about this. The failover runs fine in a normal case, so when one of the server goes down the other server load balances it. But we are not sure about  the behavior of  "restart task http" command. Does the restart http task finish all the pending threads, or Domino cluster manager switches to other server to load balance the request?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We see that after "restart task http" had executed ,  the  server logs show messages like   HTTP Server: Waiting for session to finish: Session State [Processing Request] .  So as it looks, the pending sessions are first completed by the server,

Comment: This is more of an administration question than a development question. You might be better to add it here: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/lotus-domino

Answer (score 0):

The server should close out all HTTP requests prior to shutting down and restarting.